# Compiling old C++ source files with STLEXT files

Tags: c++

I have to source for an older executable that was used for research and decompiling Slim Binary files for an Oberon system.  I cannot get the source to compile as i keep getting errors like

"from sb1d.cpp:21:
stlext/string:21:10: fatal error: stlext/stream: No such file or directory
 #include "stlext/stream"
"

Im not C++ developer by far. I work with mostly .NET (C#).  I have this folder with the stlext files but i cannot get it to compile properly.

here is a link to the source

http://web.archive.org/web/20000126051725/http://caesar.ics.uci.edu/laski/SlimBinaryDecoder.html

Comment: Looking at the project, you probably just need to add the project's root in the header search paths of your compiler.

Comment: I have tried using the -I parameter but still get the same error. I have tried to compile with cygwin and g++ as well as visual C++ 2015

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu Linux 19.04 using g++ 8.3.0.

```
g++ -I. -Isb1d sb1d/*.cpp stlext/*.cpp
```

Wildcards might not work on Mingw. Specify each source file manually in that case.

However, I have to make small changes to some files to get this compile:

*slim_error.h, line 58*

```
slim_error(slim_errno e, const string &f, const streampos &o) throw();
```

*slim_error.cpp, line 25*

```
slim_error::slim_error(slim_errno e, const string &f, const streampos &o) throw():
```

Comment: I got a version to compile with Visual C++ 2015 but it throws an error when reading the file now. I guess to follow the rules I need to come back here with a new post about that exception.  It’s an assert error.